Unity - Problems creating full screen image that maintains aspect ratio using Canvas
I am trying to create a background image that covers the entire screen of my phone, while at the same time keeps its original aspect ratio. This means that if the image and screen do not have the same aspect ratio, parts of the image will be cropped. This is acceptable. Needless to say that I want it to work with any image or screen size.
I wrote a code that uses a SpriteRenderer and it appears to work as described above. It compares the two aspect ratios, and then adjust the pixelsPerUnit accordingly. If the image aspect ratio is smaller than the screen aspect ratio, it ensures that the width of the image matches the width of the screen. Otherwise, it matches the height of the screen. I should also point that I am using an orthographic camera.
backgroundRootGO = new GameObject("Root");
backgroundImageGO = new GameObject("Image");
backgroundImageGO.transform.parent = backgroundRootGO.transform;
spriteRenderer = backgroundImageGO.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
backgroundRootGO.transform.parent = GameContext.RootGameObject.transform;

var cam = Camera.main;
var screenSizeY = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
var screenSizeX = screenSizeY * cam.aspect;
var textureSizeX = (float)texture.width;
var textureSizeY = (float)texture.height;
var pixelsPerUnit = 0.0f;
var screenAspect = screenSizeX / screenSizeY;
var textureAspect = textureSizeX / textureSizeY;
if (textureAspect < screenAspect) {
    pixelsPerUnit = textureSizeX / screenSizeX;
} else {
    pixelsPerUnit = textureSizeY / screenSizeY;
}

var spriteRect = new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height);
var spritePivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
var imageSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, spriteRect, spritePivot, pixelsPerUnit);
spriteRenderer.sprite = imageSprite;

However, I would like to produce the same result using a Canvas programmatically. Without using the Unity Editor at all. Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how to do so. I find Canvas and CanvasScaler hard to use. I understand the basic concepts like Render Mode, UI Scale Mode, etc. But things like Screen Match Mode, Match, Reference Resolution, and Anchors confuse me.
Any advice, pointers, and code snippets would be highly appreciated. I need a programmatic solution, without using the Unity Editor at all. Thank you!
PS: I am using Unity 2022.3.

It implies a "view / view box". There are different ways to accomplish that. Anything that can "unconstrain" Width and constrain Height will do. "Horizontal scrollers", for example (that don't scroll in this case). Any window limited in Height. "Negative" margins can push content "outward".

I would do this mostly in engine usuing a CanvasScaler set to Scale with screen size. You can change the Match(Width/Height) in code to match the longer edge.
